# Display Image Caption on enlarged view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, image

Basically i need to display Image name(caption) when the image in enlarged. So i tried with this sample code.

[Sample Code for Image Gallery](http://www.lateralcode.com/create-a-simple-picture-gallery-using-php/)

Demo of the same is given below

[Demo of the same](http://demo.lateralcode.com/phpgallery/)

Now what i want is when the image is **enlarged** in the left hand side there is a caption 
**Image 1 of 3**. Instead of that i need the `Image Caption` i.e `Image1.png` similar like this.

When i opened lightbox js file i found this line where it will display Image 1 of 3 line

```
if (this.imageArray.length > 1){
            this.numberDisplay.update( LightboxOptions.labelImage + ' ' + (this.activeImage + 1) + ' ' + LightboxOptions.labelOf + '  ' + this.imageArray.length).show();
        }
```

I tried to alter the code by replacing `(this.activeImage + 1)` as `(this.activeImage.value)` But its showing undefined.

How to display the name of the respective image when the image is enlarged.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to do a console.log(this) and see the details of that object in the browser console. If it exposes any property that had the image name in it then use it. For example it could be something like "this.activeImageName". If not see what's in "this.imageArray". You might be able to access something like "this.imageArray[this.activeImage].name". Do a console.log on different objects to see what properties it got.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP code,

Find

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']">';
```

Replace with

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']"> title="Whatever Title You Need or get FileName by using php"';
```